# Mirroring repository from Gitlab to Azure Devops and modification

Tags: git, azure, batch-file, jenkins, gitlab

I have created a scheduled pipeline job which creates a replica of a particular repository from Gitlab to AzureDevops. Currently it is scheduled to be executed once per day in the evening.

Now, after the mirror is done, I have a requirement to create a testbranch in the new azure devops repo, and test a few functionalities.

When the Jenkins job runs again, the entire job fails throwing an error :

```
11:16:29  warning: redirecting to https://xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/libs/Tools.git/
11:16:31  To https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/Embedded%20System%20Software%20Development/_git/Lib-Tools-BranchCheck
11:16:31   ! [remote rejected] testbranch (TF401027: You need the Git 'ForcePush' permission to perform this action. Details: identity '071e2e88-8ab9-41aa-b37b-53442cabf7b9\****', scope 'branch'.)
11:16:31  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/ENERCON-WRD/Embedded%20System%20Software%20Development/_git/BaseSW-Lib-Tools-BranchCheck'
```

The scheduled pipeline script on jenkins looks like below:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'Windows'}
    
    stages {
        stage('mirror to azure') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                        gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Gitlab_Creds', gitToolName: 'Default'),
                        gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Azure_Creds')
                    ]){
                 bat '''
                        @echo off
                        SET SOURCE_URL=https://xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/libs/Tools
                        echo "source url taken"
                        SET "TARGET_URL=https://xxxxxx@dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/Embedded%%20System%%20Software%%20Development/_git/Lib-Tools-BranchCheck"
                        echo "target url taken"
                        :run
                        git "clone" "--bare" "%SOURCE_URL%" || goto :cloneerror
                        cd "Tools.git"
                        git "push" "--mirror" "%TARGET_URL%"|| goto :pusherror
                        cd ".."
                        rd /s /q  "Tools.git"
                        echo "Done."
                        exit /b 0
                        
                        :cloneerror
                        echo "Deleting the previously cloned folder"
                        rd /s /q  "Tools.git"
                        goto :run
                        
                        
                        :pusherror 
                        echo ERROR && exit /b
                        echo "exiting abruptly..."
  
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the new branch created to remain as it is in the Azure devops repository,
but the branches modifed/created to the gitlab repository are updated on Azure as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To begin with ```echo "exiting abruptly..."``` will never be reached. `echo ERROR` will always be successful therefore `&&` (meaning 'if previous command was successful', will immediately execute the command `exit /b`. This also means you'll unlikely see the `ERROR` message printed before the `exit` closes the cmd.exe instance. Additionally, even if `echo "exiting abruptly..."` was reached the same thing would happen with that message too. For that reason I'd change `echo ERROR && exit /b` to `echo ERROR`, then move `exit /b` to the last line. I'd also include a `timeout` before both `exit`s.